# Can you get both rows affected and rows matched from a mysql UPDATE query using pymysql?

Tags: mysql, pymysql

In my application, when I submit an UPDATE query to mysql, there are three possible outcomes.

(1) One matching row is found and updated

(2) One matching row is found but the update has no effect because it doesn't change anything

(3) No matching row is found.

Pymysql's cursor.execute() function returns the number of rows affected: 1 in case (1), and 0 in cases (2) and (3).

Can I distinguish case (2) and (3) without making an extra query first to see if the row exists and whether the update would affect it?   In other words, can I get the number of rows matched in addition to the number of rows affected?

Comment: I don't think the MySQL server provides any way to distinguish them.

Comment: Can you add an extra column to the table? You could put `new_column = new_column + 1` into the update, so then it will always modify the matching rows.

Comment: Or if you have a timestamp column, you could do `timestamp = now()`

Comment: Barmar -- I like the timestamp idea.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

see [github PyMySQL issues 347 comment](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/347#issuecomment-364645189) [by methane](https://github.com/methane)

> There are two ways to know matched rows count.
>
> 1. passing client flag
>
> from pymysql.constants import CLIENT
>
> conn = pymysql.connect(..., client_flag=CLIENT.FOUND_ROWS)
>
> In this case, rowcount is rows matched with WHERE clause. (But you
>   can't know rows changed)
>
> 2. info
>
> After executed query, you can show text message by
>   print(cursor._result.message).
>
> It's same to mysql command line client shows.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-info.html